# How do I create aliases in discord.py cogs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a discord.py cog set up, ready to use. There is one issue, how do I set up aliases for commands? I'll give you my code below to see what else I need to do:

```
# Imports
from discord.ext import commands
import bot  # My own custom module


# Client commands
class Member(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # Events
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(bot.online)

    # Commands
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        pass


# Setup function
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Member(client))
```

In this case, how should I set up an alias for the `ping` command under `@commands.command()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`discord.ext.commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=aliases#discord.ext.commands.Command) objects have a [`aliases`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=aliases#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases) attribute. Here's how to use it:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['testcommand', 'testing'])
async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("This a test command")
```

You'll then be able to invoke your command by writing `!test`, `!testcommand` or `!testing` (if your command prefix is `!`).
Also, if you plan on coding a log system, [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) objects have a [`invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoked_with#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with) attribute which takes the aliase the command was invoked with as a value.

**Reference:** [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

---

**Edit:** If you want to make your cog admin only, you can overwrite the existing `cog_check` function that will trigger when a command from this cog is invoked:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class Admin(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def check_cog(self, ctx):
        admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        #False -> Won't trigger the command
        return admin in ctx.author.role
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: One other small thing, can I make a whole cog class admin only?

Comment: I've edited my answer, for other questions, please make your own researchs before asking :)