# Python - How To Make A Discord Bot Command Have Multiple "Call Words"

Tags: python, discord.py

Not sure of the wording on this one, sorry!

I have a command 'kick', that I want to have multiple words that can call it without having to write the function again. e.g. 'Kick', 'Boot'

```
@bot.command(name="kick", help="Kicks a person from the server")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick_user(ctx, user: discord.Member, reason=None):
    if not reason:
        await user.kick()
        print('err1')
        await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **No Reason**")
    else:
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        print('err2')
        await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **{reason}**")
```

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
call_commands = ["kick", "Kick", "boot"]
@bot.command(name=call_commands, help="Kicks a person from the server")
```

Any help much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062718/how-do-i-create-aliases-in-discord-py-cogs) answer your question?

Comment: @itzFlubby Just what I needed thanks!